Dockerを用いた上でVSCodeで".ipynb"ファイルを操作できるようにする環境構築に関する質問
目的

VSCode (Cursor) で.ipynbファイルを操作できるようにする
環境はDockerコンテナ内で完結させ、ローカルにPythonを入れない

背景
コンサルティングファームに勤めています。
プロジェクトによってはDSのロールで機械学習モデルの構築やデータ分析を行うことがあります。
従来、ローカル環境でAnacondaをインストールしJupyter Notebookを使用しておりましたが、ローカルに様々なライブラリを入れることをやめたいと思い、Dockerを用いた環境を構築したいと思いました。
また、Jupyter Notebookではコード補完機能が使用できないのでVSCode (Cursor) 上でコーディングしていきたいと考えています。
困っていること
VScodeからdocker内のjupyterを使う
上記の記事を参考に作業しましたがうまくできません。
ChatGPTに全ての設定ファイルのコードやVSCodeE上の画面をアップロードし壁打ちしていますが、未だできていない状況です。
できない点としては、Docker build後、VSCode上で.ipynbファイルを操作する時、kernelを選択すると思いますが、そのkernelでJupyterを選択することができず、実行ができないという状態です。
当方、DockerとPythonの基礎知識は持っています。




「そのkernelでjupyterを選択することができず」とのことですが、ではどんな選択肢が表示されていますか？そこまでの操作は全て https://note.com/k_fukunaka/n/nabb5cd028595 の通りに行いましたか？

コメントいただきありがとうございます。
「Select Kernel」をクリックすると、上のバーに「Type to choose a kernel extentions」と表示され、サジェストで「Install/Enable suggested extensions」と「Browse maketplace for kernel extensions」と表示されます。
しかし、環境設定のファイルでJupyterを指定してコンテナビルドしているため、今の環境にはJupyterがあるはずです。正しく認識されていない原因がわからない状態です。
繰り返しになりますが、設定ファイルのコードは参考URLと同一で、変更していません。

ディレクトリ名 .devcontainer であるべきところを devcontainer と作ってしまっているのではないでしょうか。（"「開発コンテナー：コンテナ―で再度開く」を選択してもOKです。" ができてないのに無視して進んでませんか?）

quickquipさん
コメントいただきありがとうございます。
2点確認しました。
1.
ご指摘のとおり、".devcontainer"のフォルダを"devcontainer"で作成しておりました。
しかし、"."をフォルダ名につけられないようで、2枚目に添付したスクリーンショットの通りエラーになり変更ができませんでした。



"「開発コンテナー：コンテナ―で再度開く」を選択してもOKです。"
上記はVSCODEのサジェストで右下にメッセージが出てくるので、そこから実施しています。そのため、できていると当方認識しております。

試してみまして記事の通りで問題なく動きました。"そのため、できていると当方認識しております。"と書かれていますが、「開発コンテナー：コンテナ―で再度開く」でDocker Desktopが自動で起動してきましたか? 単純に私はVS Code上のエクスプローラー上で右クリックから"名前の変更"でdevcontainer←→.devcontainer の名前の変更ができました。ディレクトリ名をdevcontainerにすると「開発コンテナー：コンテナ―で再度開く」を選択してもコンテナが自動で動かないです。"devcontainer"にした時点で記事の通りになっていない、だから期待通り動かない、というだけの話でしかないように思います。

quickquipさん
コメントいただきありがとうございます。
ご指摘の通り、VSCODE上でフォルダ名に"."をつけることに成功し、jupyterが動くにようになりました。
本当にありがとうございます。
自分がフォルダ名に"."入れられないという固定概念があり気づくことができませんでした。
大変感謝しております。
